# Byte Array not size that ".length" says it is

Tags: java, client, server, broadcasting

Ok, so I have a server cient program(java) for broadcasting the server screen to the client. I convert the image to a byte array and send that to the client. Im having issues sending multiple byte arrays as after the first one is sent and recieved by the client, I get errors for the second byte array. On the server side I have the code:

```
                imageInByte=baos.toByteArray();
                outToClient.writeInt(imageInByte.length);
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(imageInByte.length));
```

This tells the client the size of the byte array coming in. On the client I have the code:

```
            int c = inFromServer.readInt();
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(c));
```

This is all well and good and the size that is estimated on the server is the size that the client receives and prints but when I actual try to write the byte array to the dataoutputstream, the byte array that the client receives is nothing like what ".length" estimated.

For example the first byte array is said to be 118207(without sending the actual byte array.

Then when I try to send the first byte array to the client, the client receives it as 118207.

The second one which without trying to actual write the array was 126205 but when I try to write the object the size is -2555936

The third one is supposed to be 125709 but comes out at the client as 1229324289 bytes.

This is driving me crazy and I have a project due next Thursday and cant continue without sorting this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated and if this is in a weird layout or you dont understand me just ask questions .Thanks.

Comment: Solved this problem by using an ObjectOutputStream rather than a dataoutputstream.